# R, conditionally remove duplicated row - based on closest to a particular value

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a dataframe in R containing the columns ID, Sex, Height and Age_Months. For each ID, there may be multiple entries of height at various ages (i.e. there may be multiple duplicate rows in ID e.g. all of value P0001 which each has a different height and age_months in that row).

I would like to be able to remove rows where ID is duplicated, but conditional upon the age_months so that I am left with the closest age_months to a pre-specified number.

Hopefully this makes sense but also to provide an example...

Here I would like to select the age closest to 96 months when there is more than one entry for an individual - therefore to remove the 1st and 2nd rows where ID = P0003

```
ID, SEX, HEIGHT, AGE_MONTHS

P0001 1 120.5 87
P0002 0 129.6 84
P0003 1 150.8 103
P0003 1 139.5 99
P0003 1 126.2 97
P0004 0 168.4 101
P0005 0 117.1 82
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think about the condition when two rows have the same absolute age difference. If that happens, which one you want to keep? The solution here does not consider that.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# Create example data frame
dat <- fread("ID SEX HEIGHT AGE_MONTHS
             P0001 1 120.5 87
             P0002 0 129.6 84
             P0003 1 150.8 103
             P0003 1 139.5 99
             P0003 1 126.2 97
             P0004 0 168.4 101
             P0005 0 117.1 82")

# Set target age
target_age <- 96

# Subset the data
dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(AGE_Diff = abs(AGE_MONTHS - target_age)) %>%
  arrange(ID, AGE_Diff) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-AGE_Diff)
```

#### Update

If you want to specify different target age for different `ID`, you can create a data frame storing the information first, then use `left_join` to merge the table.

```
# Set target age for each ID
taget_age_df <- data_frame(ID = c("P0001", "P0002", "P0003", "P0004", "P0005"),
                           Target_Age = c(86, 88, 96, 100, 82))

# Subset the data
dat2 <- dat %>%
  left_join(taget_age_df, by = "ID") %>%
  mutate(AGE_Diff = abs(AGE_MONTHS - Target_Age)) %>%
  arrange(ID, AGE_Diff) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-AGE_Diff, -Target_Age)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is called 'dat' and 'dff' is the difference.

```
library(data.table)
dat=as.data.table(dat)
dff=86

dat[unique(sapply(with(dat,sapply(ID,function(x)which(x==ID))),function(x) x[which((dat$Age[x]-dff) == min((dat$Age[x]-dff)))] )),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is one minimum `age` per `id`

Create sample data table

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  id=c("P001","P003","P003","P003","P004"),
  age=c(90,95,98,99,100),
  sex=c(1,0,1,1),
  height=c(120.5,160.2,180.4,190.3)
)
```

And then

```
for (i in dt$id)
{
  min_age <- dt[id==i,min(age)]
  height_to_keep <- dt[id==i & age==min_age,height]
  sex_to_keep <- dt[id==i & age==min_age,sex]
  dt[id==i,age:=min_age]
  dt[id==i,sex:=sex_to_keep]
  dt[id==i,height:=height_to_keep]
}
dt <- unique(dt)
```